# collision detection with code

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am new to programming and really need help now. I have been looking for an answer I think for the past two month. I'm using Xcode and objective-c. My question is about collision detection. There are thousands of example on what to do when 2 rectangle collide using CGRECT, such as alert or flip screen or play sound ext, but nothing anywhere about doing NOTHING lol! All I want is my object not going through the other object! That is all I want to keep dragging it on the screen. I just don't want the 2 object on top of each other and it seems like I'm the only online in the world that wants to do that because I can't find anything. So please help and since I'm new .. as simple as possible please so here :

```
#import "YellowDot.h"

@interface YellowDot ()

@end

@implementation YellowDot
@synthesize Dot;
@synthesize CollisionImage;

-(void) touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event

{

UITouch *Drag = [ [  event allTouches ] anyObject ];
Dot.center = [ Drag locationInView: self.view ];

[self checkCollison];

}

-(void) checkCollison
{

if (CGRectIntersectsRect(Dot.frame, CollisionImage.frame))

{
AudioServicesPlaySystemSound(playSoundId);

}


}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{

NSURL *SoundURL = [ NSURL fileURLWithPath:[[NSBundle mainBundle]           pathForResource:@"beep"ofType:@"wav"]];
AudioServicesCreateSystemSoundID((__bridge CFURLRef)SoundURL, & playSoundId);


[super viewDidLoad];
// Do any additional setup after loading the view.


}


and here is the .h file :

#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import <AudioToolbox/AudioToolbox.h>

@interface YellowDot : UIViewController

{

IBOutlet UIImageView *Dot;
IBOutlet UIImageView *CollisionImage;
SystemSoundID playSoundId;

}

@property (nonatomic, retain) UIImageView *Dot;

@property (nonatomic, retain) UIImageView *CollisionImage;


@end
```

So what could go in there ?  It's already playing a sound when colliding as you can see but that's it. Dot is the image that I'm dragging around the screen and Collision image is the one that I want Dot to collide with but stop as a wall. Hope its clear enough ( I'm French,  so sorry for the bad writing) :S Thank you.

Comment: hoo ok that kinda make sense ? without giving me the answer could you give me a hint on how to code that .. i tried few things but didn't help :s

Answer (score 1):

Given that you're successfully detecting the collision, the answer would seem to be that if the move causes a collision, then don't update the object to the new position.  Just don't update Dot.center. The sequence would be: get a touch event for the move, precompute the place where the object is going to be, if no collision, move it; if collision, don't update it's location.

Note that OpenGL might be better suited to this type of thing, given you're going to do a lot of it.